Showing random variable is not measurable wrt. a sigma-algebra
Let $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$ be independent random variables on $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ with positive variance.
Let
\begin{align}
X &= \epsilon_1 \\
Y &= g(X) + \epsilon_2
\end{align}
where $g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is some measurable transformation. I wish to show that $X$ is not $\sigma(Y)$-measurable. In the case where $g(x) = 0$ for all $x$ I have shown this by proof of contradiction, where by noting that then $X$ and $Y$ are independent, and if $X$ is $\sigma(Y)$-measurable we could for every $E_1 \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ find an associated set $E_2 \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ such that
$$
(X \in E_1) = (Y \in E_2)
$$
But then
$$
P(X \in E_1) = P(X \in E_1, Y \in E_2) = P(X \in E_1) P(Y \in E_2) = P(X \in E_1)^2
$$
Picking any set $E_1$ with $0 < P(X\in E_1) < 1$ yields the contradiction, and such set exists since $\epsilon_1$ has positive variance.
But I am not quite sure how to show this for the case where $g$ is not identically $0$. Using the same strategy, we could by contradiction assume that for every $E_1$ there exists $E_2$ such that
$$
(X \in E_1 ) = (Y \in E_2) = (g(X) + \epsilon_2 \in E_2)
$$
Now, $X-g(X)$ is independent of $Y-g(X) = \epsilon_2$ and if the contradiction hypothesis means that for every $\tilde{E}_1$ we can find $\tilde{E}_2$ such that
\begin{align}
(X-g(X) \in \tilde{E}_1)=(Y-g(X) \in \tilde{E}_2)
\end{align}
we would be done by a similar argument as above. I have therefore tried to show the property, namely by fixing some arbitrary $\tilde{E}_1 \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ and finding the corresponding $\tilde{E}_2$ such that $(X-g(X) \in \tilde{E}_1)=(Y-g(X) \in \tilde{E}_2)$. In particular, we can let $E_1 := f^{-1}(\tilde{E}_1)$, where $f(x) = x-g(x)$, and then we have that there exists $E_2$ such that
$$
(X-g(X) \in \tilde{E}_1) = (f(X) \in \tilde{E}_1) = (X \in f^{-1}(\tilde{E}_1)) = 
(X \in E_1) = (Y \in E_2)
$$
But the problem then becomes: how do we pick $\tilde{E}_2$ such that $(Y \in E_2) = (Y-g(X) \in \tilde{E}_2)$? I do not see the solution

Are you sure this is true? What if you try defining an example where it is NOT true? You just need to get $X$ as a measurable function of $Y$. For example, you might consider $X \sim Bernoulli(1/2)$ and $g(x)=x$.

@Michael Thank you very much for your reply. That cleared it up for me. I have written an answer showing the counterexample using your example. I will attempt to prove that the claim holds if $\epsilon_2$ has support on the whole real line.

The claim does not hold. As pointed out by @Michael, we can construct the following counterexample.
\begin{align}
\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2 &\overset{\text{iid}} \sim \text{Bernoulli}(1/2)\\
X&= \epsilon_1 \\
Y&= X + 2 \epsilon_2
\end{align}
Then we have
\begin{align}
Y&=0 \Rightarrow X= 0 \\
Y&=1 \Rightarrow X= 1 \\
Y&=2 \Rightarrow X= 0 \\
Y&=3 \Rightarrow X= 1 
\end{align}
We have that $\sigma(X) = \{\emptyset, \Omega,(X=0), (X=1)\}$. For $Y$, we have that $\sigma(Y)$ is generated by the sets
$$
\{(Y=0),(Y=1),(Y=2),(Y=3)\}.
$$
But the above calculation shows that $(X=0) = (Y=0) \cup (Y=2)\in \sigma(Y)$ and likewise $(X=1) = (Y=1) \cup (Y=3) \in \sigma(Y)$. In other words,
$$
\sigma(X) \subseteq \sigma(Y),
$$
i.e. $X$ is measurable wrt. $\sigma(Y)$.
